# Fatal error: Call to a member function base_url() on a non-object Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payumoney

> Fatal error: Call to a member function base_url() on a non-object

I am getting the above error when I redirect to the site from payment gateway, hence the head file containing all the scripts does not get loaded

I tried using `$ci =& get_instance();` But still its giving the same issue

```
public function payment_success() { 
    $this->load->model("bidding_m"); 
    $this->load->model("admin_setting_m"); 
    $this->load->model("channel_partners_m"); //call model functions to update the tables 
    $this->load->config('payu_config', TRUE); 
    $this->config = $this->config->item('payu_config'); 
    //echo base_url();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: i tried that still it is giving the same issue. "I mentioned I get it After redirect from payment gateway"

Comment: pls read the question properly before marking it as negative

Comment: I guess its marked negative because with this information it's hard to help. Can you provide more code and what you tried besides the line you showed?

Comment: I added your code to your question, otherwise it's impossible to read.

Comment: public function payment_success() {

  $this->load->model("bidding_m");
  
         //call model functions to update the tables
  $this->load->config('payu_config', TRUE);
  $this->config = $this->config->item('payu_config'); //next check salt for payu 
        $this->data['subview'] = 'projects/project_details';
    $this->load->view('layout_main',$this->data); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
$this->config = $this->config->item('payu_config');
```

I don't know if this code is in library / controller so I tried explain it for both:

**Controller:**

You rewrite whole config ($this->config = ...) with a single config item and your *base_url* config item is lost! So do it this way:

```
$config = $this->config->item('payu_config');
```

**Library:**

You are accessing config item, but don't have instance of codeigniter. If this code is in library, it should looks like this:

```
public function payment_success() { 
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $ci->load->model("bidding_m"); 
    $ci->load->model("admin_setting_m"); 
    $ci->load->model("channel_partners_m"); 
    $ci->load->config('payu_config', TRUE); 
    //if you have in this library variable $config
    $this->config = $ci->config->item('payu_config'); 
    echo base_url();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , the code was in the controller I removed the custom config file, Its working

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the helper like so

Filename first letterupper case

**Somelibraryname.php**

```
<?php

class Somelibraryname  {

  public function __construct() {
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->helper('url');
  }

  public function something() {
    echo base_url();

    // Or

    echo $this->CI->config->item('base_url');
  } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but nope.. didnt work .. Its not loading the url helper .. anything els i can try ?

Comment: @san Did you try the config item()

Comment: yes it says Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object

Comment: Have you named the file name and class name where first letter only upper case